# .Net MVC When to use OnActionExecuting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Some very basic question.

When to initialize or assign in OnActionExecuting?

Very simple scenario:

```
public partial class OrderController : DefaultController
{
    private int customerId = 0;

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        customerId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Should I assign customerId in **OnActionExecuting** so I can reuse it in code in each action?

- Readability
- Eliminating repeating

or should I just assign it in separate actions each time?

- We do not need this assignment or in case of initialization of some object in each action)?

Comment: Best way looks like CustomAuthorizatoinAttribute and override Authorize()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is, of course, *it depends* on your team's coding style and other circumstances.

Another option you haven't considered is creating  a [custom action filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to contain this logic, and reuse it with only one line of code above the action-method signature.

Then if you decide to apply it to all/any action-methods, you  can apply it to the controller, or to a base-controller even.

Comment: Custom action filter is very clean and proper way yes. I want to eliminate as much code from controller as possible.